# Underline text with custom line per row

Tags: css

I need to style underline in my headings. I tried with :before and :after and it does work when my headline is in one row, if it's to long and it breaks only the last row is underlined I get why is that but is there any other way where I will be able to underline my every row?

Comment: Just use `text-decoration: underline`?

Comment: I need to style that line

Comment: You can: use `text-decoration: underline dotted red;` for example. See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-color/

Comment: @NenadDrobac see here :https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp